# Azure DevOps Pipelines running on incorrect branches

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, yaml

I'm attempting to build different branches with different YAML configuration files in each branch. However, when I commit to a branch that should only trigger 1 pipeline it triggers both.

[image: Project Pipelines]

Development YAML:

```
    trigger:
    - master_Development
    
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    
    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
      buildPackageDirectory: 'packages'
      nugetConfig: 'SW.Api.Net/nuget.config'
    
    steps:
    
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
      displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 4.4.1
    
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet restore'
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: $(solution)
        feedsToUse: config
        nugetConfigPath: $(nugetConfig)
        externalFeedCredentials: TelerikFeed
        restoreDirectory: $(buildPackageDirectory)
    
    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build solution'
      inputs:
        solution: $(solution)
        msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
        platform: $(buildPlatform)
        configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
    
    - task: VSTest@2
      displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
      inputs:
        testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=Unit Test'
        platform: $(buildPlatform)
        configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
    
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
      inputs:
        PathToPublish: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
        ArtifactName: 'drop'
      condition: succeededOrFailed()


Production YAML:

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  buildPackageDirectory: 'packages'
  nugetConfig: 'SW.Api.Net/nuget.config'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 4.4.1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: $(solution)
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: $(nugetConfig)
    externalFeedCredentials: TelerikFeed
    restoreDirectory: $(buildPackageDirectory)

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution'
  inputs:
    solution: $(solution)
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
    platform: $(buildPlatform)
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testFiltercriteria: 'TestCategory=Unit Test'
    platform: $(buildPlatform)
    configuration: $(buildConfiguration)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathToPublish: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Why would the pipelines not be separately triggering they target different branches?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue, it had to do with the path to the pipeline.

I created a directory called pipelines/dev and pipelines/prod in the root of my repo. And I pointed either build pipeline to the respective yaml config file. Now it will only build on the commit of the specific branches.